# How to call XIB in my existing XIB?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, xib

Description:- I am coding for a custom framework, For this I am using XIB everywhere, Now I want to call another XIB in my existing XIB, Its calling very fine But unable to perform button action of called XIB. Thanks in advance Here is code.

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self)) 
let nib = UINib(nibName: "WelcomeVC", bundle: bundle) 
self.contentView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView 
self.addSubview(self.contentView)
```

Comment: Add your code plz

Comment: let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self)) let nib = UINib(nibName: "WelcomeVC", bundle: bundle) self.contentView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView self.addSubview(self.contentView) Its working fine but the button action I have created in "WelcomeVC" is not working.

Comment: Try to type cast to your own view not uiview self.contentView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC - is global iOS concept. Learn it again.
xib - is view "V", "V" - cant been as controller "C".
if you can call xib - make it in a controller.

Comment: if that view is adding inside any viewcontroller already then no need to add new view to controller